# mutation testing reachability infection and propagation

Tags: mutation-testing

Hey guys i have a question about mutation testing here is the sample code

```
//Effects: If numbers null throw NullPointException
// else return LAST occurance of val in numbers[]
//If val not in numbers [] return -1
 
public static int findVal (int numbers[], int val)
{
 int findVal = -1;
for( int i = 0 ;  i < numbers.length ; i++)     // for( int i = 1 ;  i < numbers.length ; i++)
 
if( numbers[i] == val)
findVal = i;
return (findVal);
}
```

(a) If possible, find a test input that does not reach the mutant.

(b) If possible, find a test input that satisfies reachability but not infection for the mutant.

(c) If possible, find a test input that satisfies infection, but not propagation for the mutant.

(d) If possible, find a test input that kills mutant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include a definition for reachability, infection, and propagation in your question -- I am assuming the following:

- reachability: execution of the mutated expression
- infection: the value of the mutated expression differs from the value of the original (unmutated) expression
- propagation: the infected state (different expression value) leads to infection of an observable state

Also note that (d) not only depends on the input but also on the test oracle -- achieving propagation does not imply killing the mutant.

The following inputs satisfy your requirements:

(a) There exists no such input; the loop initializer `int i = 0` is executed for every input, even if `numbers` is null and consequently `numbers.length` raises a NullPointerException. Note that only a test that does not call the `findVal` method can't reach the mutant -- calling `findVal` implies satisfying reachability for this mutant.

(b) There exists no such input; the mutated expression is independent of the method parameters (`i=0` != `i=1` for any input) -- satisfying reachability implies satisfying infection for this mutant.

(c) `numbers` is an empty array; if `numbers.length` is 0, then the initial value of `i` (for any `i`>=0) doesn't matter, even though the state of `i` is infected. Passing in null for `numbers` is another example that satisfies infection but not propagation.

(d) `numbers` is a one-element array, whose element value equals `val`. There are many inputs that satisfy propagation, which means that the mutant can be killed -- whether the test actually kills the mutant depends on whether the test asserts on the outcome.